# Looping Input PHP

Tags: php

Good day. I have this Input form. How to `loop` an Input with PHP.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
Name 1 : <input type="text" name='fName[]' />
Name 2 : <input type="text" name='fName[]' />
Name 3 : <input type="text" name='fName[]' />
<br />
Age 1 : <input type="text" name='fAge[]' />
Age 2 : <input type="text" name='fAge[]' />
Age 3 : <input type="text" name='fAge[]' />
<button type="submit" name="sbmt"> Submit </button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sbmt']))
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['fName']);
        echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['fAge']);
    }

?>
```

Here is the output example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name1
    [1] => Name2
    [2] => Name3
)
Array
(
    [0] => Age1
    [1] => Age2
    [2] => Age3
)
```

Well, above is working fine. My question Is, How can i achieve this.

```
Name : Name1;Name2;Name3;
Age  : Age1;Age2;Age3;
```

Comment: php has many loops, for arrays usually: `foeach()` is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) would do the trick for you. This function converts your array into a string, joining them using a 'glue' (in this case, the glue is semicolon ;)

Try this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sbmt'])) {
        echo "Name:". implode(';', $_POST['fName']) . ';';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "Agee:". implode(';', $_POST['fAge']) . ';';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implode function to concat an array by a separator like a so:

```
print 'Name : ' . implode(';', $_POST['fName']);
print 'Age : ' . implode(';', $_POST['fAge']);
```

If you really want to loop through your data (which is, what your title says), you can achieve this by using foreach:

```
print 'Name : ';
foreach ($_POST['fName'] as $name) {
    print $name . ';';
}

print 'Age: ';
foreach ($_POST['fAge'] as $age) {
    print $age. ';';
}
```